# Ansible AWX issue when running playbook from WebGUI

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ovirt

I have recently configured Ansible AWX, the hosts file on /etc/ansible is populated by two server groups:

```
[ovirtmanager]

10.0.0.10

[ovirthv]

10.0.0.100
10.0.0.101
```

Via CLI my playbook called check-service-status.yml runs correctly

```yaml
---
- hosts: ovirthv
  become: no
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: "Populate service facts"
    service_facts:
  - name: "See if the service <lldpad> is up and running"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ansible_facts.services['lldpad.service'].state}}"
  - name: "See if the service <fcoe> is up and running"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ansible_facts.services['fcoe.service'].state}}"
```

Using the WebGUI I get this message:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: ovirthv
PLAY [ovirthv] *****************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

How can I solve this problem? What's wrong?
Thank you very much!

UPDATE: here is the playbook execution via WebGUI

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.18
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/var/lib/awx/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 24 2020, 17:57:11) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /tmp/bwrap_81_i8uuuftw/awx_81_j5jul0vn/tmpn1f0jauv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /tmp/bwrap_81_i8uuuftw/awx_81_j5jul0vn/tmpn1f0jauv inventory source with script plugin
Skipping callback 'actionable', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'awx_display', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'counter_enabled', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'debug', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'dense', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'full_skip', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'json', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
```

Comment: `What's wrong? ` => hard to give a definitive answer with so little information but it looks like your inventory is not correctly set inside awx since ansible cannot find any group named `ovirthv` or any hosts inside it. Did you create the inventory? Did you import it correctly from your cvs source (If relevant)? Did you associate/select the correct inventory in your job/template?

Comment: I have an inventory under Resources-Inventories called oVirt Inventory contains all the hosts in my test environment. Actually its disabled and I can't find any option on WebGUI to enable.

Comment: Solved by correct configuration in inventory